# Best Way to move VIEW UP when keyboard appears in AUTOLAYOUT iOS?

Tags: ios, uiview, keyboard

I have done this so many time using FRAME.

```
//method to move the view up/down whenever the keyboard is shown/dismissed
-(void)setViewMovedUp:(BOOL)movedUp
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3]; // if you want to slide up the view

    CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
    if (movedUp)
    {
        // 1. move the view's origin up so that the text field that will be hidden come above the keyboard
        // 2. increase the size of the view so that the area behind the keyboard is covered up.
        rect.origin.y -= kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
        rect.size.height += kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
    }
    else
    {
        // revert back to the normal state.
        rect.origin.y += kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
        rect.size.height -= kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
    }
    self.view.frame = rect;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

However, What is best way to move View up in AutoLayout (Constraints)?

If I use above method, It streches my SubViews, as They have constraints of different types.

Thanks

Comment: create properties from your constraint then change it's value, or use `view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES`

Comment: Its self.view, I think we can't apply constraints on it from TOP.@Tj3n

Comment: it will be easy for you if you keep your views inside a scroll view and put the scrollview as as child to main view. there are lots of tutorials online to do that in autolayouts
http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/

Answer (score 0):

If it's `self.view`, Use this code to push whole view up without worry about constraint

```
self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD);
```

Then revert it to change the View back to normal :D Your constraint wont be affected

Comment: I have already done this. I can do it. I am asking is there any way in AutoLayout, means using constraints, else with Frame I can write much better logic :)

Comment: Hm...Your self.view doesnt have any constraint, how can u want to use it to push the view up??

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work. Test after removing these lines `rect.size.height += kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;` and  `rect.size.height -= kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;`.  These lines are not required as you do not need to cover the area behind keyboard.

Besides, there are multiple ways to achieve this using autolayout based on the requirement. 
For example: To move the whole view upside you can create an invisible-view of 1 pixel at top in main view. Set constraints for 1-pixel-view. Every other sub-views' constraints must be applied in such a way that sub-views can move up and down if you change the top space constraint of 1-pixel-view. ***Even that 1-pixel-view is not required if you can use the subview at top in such a manner***

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard find view bottom constraint and bind IBOutlet to ViewController.

[image]

Then just change the value of constraint when keyboard will appear. There is example below.

```
@IBOutlet weak var sendPhoneButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

var originConstraintConstant : CGFloat = 0.0;

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    registerKeyboardListeners()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    originConstraintConstant = bottomConstraint.constant
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    deregisterKeyboardListeners()
}

func registerKeyboardListeners() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(LogInViewController.keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(LogInViewController.keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

func deregisterKeyboardListeners(){
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
        let userInfo = notification.userInfo
        let keyboardSize = userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue
        bottomConstraint.constant = keyboardSize.cgRectValue.height
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: Notification) {
    bottomConstraint.constant = originConstraintConstant
}
```